# How to configure Owned type referencing another entity in ef core 6

Tags: c#, ef-core-6.0

I have the following entity called Slot.

```
public class Slot : Entity
{
    public virtual SnackPile SnackPile { get; set; }
}
```

SnackPile here is a ValueObject and has no table of its own. Its owned by Slot. SnackPile looks like this.

```
public sealed class SnackPile : ValueObject<SnackPile>
{
    public static readonly SnackPile Empty = new SnackPile(Snack.None, 0, 0m);
    public Snack Snack { get; } // Please note this Snack, we will come to this.
    public int Quantity { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; }
    private SnackPile() { }
}
```

So to configure that, I have the following.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Slot>().OwnsOne(slot => slot.SnackPile, slotToSnackpile =>
{
    slotToSnackpile.Property(ss => ss.Price).IsRequired();
    slotToSnackpile.Property(ss => ss.Quantity).IsRequired();
    //slotToSnackpile.Navigation(p => p.Snack).IsRequired(); // This is not working.
}).Navigation(slot => slot.SnackPile).IsRequired();
```

So far so good.

Now the SnackPile has as a property Snack, and this an entity. How to configure this?
As you can see there, I tried to add this

```
slotToSnackpile.Navigation(p => p.Snack).IsRequired(); // This is not working.
```

It gives the following error.

```
Navigation 'SnackPile.Snack' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.
```

Tried the following two as well, but to no avail.

```
//slotToSnackpile.Property(ss => ss.Snack).IsRequired();
```

This gives the following error. `The property 'SnackPile.Snack' is of type 'Snack' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

And with this one

```
//slotToSnackpile.Property(ss => ss.Snack.Id).IsRequired();
```

I get the error. `The expression 'ss => ss.Snack.Id' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')`

Stuck :( Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core maps by default only properties (primitive or navigation like) having public getter **and any setter** (could be private, protected etc.).

Since all your properties (including the one in question) are *get only* (have no setters), you have to map them explicitly.

For primitive properties you use `Property` fluent API. But for navigation properties you need the relationship fluent API, e.g. `Has` / `With` pair. In your case:

```cs
slotToSnackpile.HasOne(e => e.Snack).WithMany().IsRequired();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, its working. Any way to configure the name of the resulting column? Tried slotToSnackpile.HasOne(e => e.Snack).WithMany().HasColumnName("Snack");  Added HasColumnName at the end, but this not compiling.

Comment: @VivekDev With this API you could configure the shadow FK property name, e.g.  `.HasForeignKey("SnackId")`. Then you can configure the its column name as usual with `.HasColumnName`, e.g. `slotToSnackpile.Property("SnackId").HasColumnName("Snack");`

Comment: Need to understand more about shadow FK. Thanks Anyway, I will look into it.